# Not able to click on drop down menu on Nav bar

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am using simple nav bar with drop downs. However I am not able to click on any of them. Below is the code

```css
.search-box{
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#btn1{
    background-color:transparent;
}

.top-banner{
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#595959 ;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 200px;
}

.dropdown-menu.columns-3 {
    min-width: 600px;
}
.dropdown-menu li a {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.multi-column-dropdown {
    list-style: none;
}
.multi-column-dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    color: #333;
    white-space: normal;
}
.multi-column-dropdown li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #262626;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .dropdown-menu.multi-column {
        min-width: 240px !important;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="top-banner">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-11">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse">

                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" >Movie Flix</a>
                    <input type="search" class="search-box" placeholder="Search" >
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Type <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Movies</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Series</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Genre <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Adventure</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Sci-Fi</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Thriller</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Crime</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Talkshow</a></li>


                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                            <li><a href="#">Drama</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Fantasy</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Comedy</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Biography</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Documentary</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">War</a></li>


                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                            <li><a href="#">Mystery</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Romance</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Western</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Animation</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Horror</a></li>

                                            <li><a href="#">Family</a></li>

                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ul>
                        </li>


                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--/.navbar-collapse-->
            </nav>
        </div>


    </div>
```

I am using Gulp to add all the dependencies, 
After adding dependencies my index.html looks like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="movieflix">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<!--bower:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<!--endinject-->
<!--vendor:css-->
<!--endinject-->
<!--inject:css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/catalog.tmpl.css">
<!--endinject-->
<!--app:css-->
<!--endinject-->
<body>
<header>

</header>
<section  ng-view>

</section>
<footer>

</footer>
<!--bower:js-->
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!--endinject-->
<!--inject:js-->
<script src="app/modules/movieflixmodule.js"></script>
<script src="app/services/login.service.js"></script>
<script src="app/services/catalog.service.js"></script>
<script src="app/controllers/signup.controller.js"></script>
<script src="app/controllers/login.controller.js"></script>
<script src="app/controllers/catalog.controller.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<!--endinject-->

<!--vendor:js-->
<!--endinject-->

<!--app:js-->
<!--endinject-->
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my Gulp file

```js
gulp=require('gulp'),
clean =require('gulp-clean'),
inject=require('gulp-inject'),
bowerfiles=require('main-bower-files'),
gulpfilter=require('gulp-filter'),
angularFileSort=require('gulp-angular-filesort'),
concat=require('gulp-concat'),
cleanCss=require('gulp-clean-css'),
cleanJS=require('gulp-uglify'),
merge=require('merge-stream'),
browserSync=require('browser-sync').create();

var config={
  paths:{
      src:'./src',
      build:'./build',
      bower:'./bower_components'
  }
};

gulp.task('clean',function(){

return gulp.src(config.paths.build,{read:false}).pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('inject',function(){
   var cssFiles=gulp.src([config.paths.src+'/**/*.css'],{read:false});

   var jsFiles=gulp.src([config.paths.src+'/**/*.js']);

   return gulp.src(config.paths.src+'/index.html').
   pipe(inject(gulp.src(bowerfiles(),{read:false}),{name:'bower'}))
       .pipe(inject(cssFiles,{
       ignorePath:'src',addRootSlash:false
   })).
   pipe(inject(jsFiles.pipe(angularFileSort()),{
       ignorePath:'src',addRootSlash:false
   })).pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.build));

});

gulp.task('serve',['inject'],function(){
    browserSync.init({
        server:{
            baseDir:[config.paths.build,config.paths.bower,config.paths.src],
            routes:{
             '/bower_components':'bower_components'
            }
        },
        files:[
            config.paths.src+'/**'
        ]

    })
});

gulp.task('minifyCss',function(){
var vendorStyles=gulp.src(bowerfiles()).pipe(gulpfilter(['**/*.css'])).
    pipe(concat('vendor.min.css')).
    pipe(cleanCss({debug:true})).
    pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.build+'/styles'));

var appStyles=gulp.src(config.paths.src+'/**/*.css').
    pipe(concat('app.min.css')).
    pipe(cleanCss({debug:true})).
    pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.build+'/styles'));

return merge(vendorStyles,appStyles);
});

gulp.task('minifyJS',function(){
    var vendorJS=gulp.src(bowerfiles()).pipe(gulpfilter(['**/*.js'])).
        pipe(concat('vendor.min.js')).
        pipe(cleanJS({debug:true})).
        pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.build+'/scripts'));

var appJS=gulp.src(config.paths.src+'/**/*.js').
    pipe(angularFileSort()).
    pipe(concat('app.min.js')).
    pipe(cleanJS({debug:true})).
    pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.build+'/scripts'));

return merge(vendorJS,appJS);


});

gulp.task('html',function(){
    return gulp.src([config.paths.src+'/**/*.html','!'+config.paths.src+'/index.html'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.build));

});

gulp.task('fonts',function(){
    return gulp.src(bowerfiles()).pipe(gulpfilter(['**/*.{svg,eot,tt,woff,woff2}'])).
        pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.build+'/fonts'));
});

gulp.task('other',function(){
    return gulp.src([config.paths.src+'/**/*','!**/*.html','!**/*.css','!**/*.js']).
        pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.build+'/other'));
});


gulp.task('build',['html','fonts','other','minifyJS','minifyCss'],function(){
    var vendorFiles=gulp.src([config.paths.build+'/styles/vendor.min.css',config.paths.build+'/scripts/vendor.min.js'],{read:false});
    var appFiles=gulp.src([config.paths.build+'/styles/app.min.css',config.paths.build+'/scripts/app.min.js'],{read:false});


    return gulp.src(config.paths.src+'/index.html').
        pipe(inject(vendorFiles ,{name:'vendor',ignorePath:'build',addRootSlash:false})).
        pipe(inject(appFiles,{name:'app',ignorePath:'build',addRootSlash:false})).
    pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.build));

});
```

I was not able to figure what is wrong with my code. I am not able to click on the drop downs on nav bar.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code. Apologies for dumping all the code.

Appreciate any help

Thank you

Comment: The dropdown seems fine. Can you be more specific about the issue.

Comment: Hi Dan, when I click on the drop down,drop down list is not displayed.

Comment: Can you post your gulp file?

Comment: Hi @TirthrajBarot, jus updated the gulp file. Could please tell me what could be the issue.

Comment: As it works perfect before gulp,  there can be either ordering issue or injector moduler error.. But as you don't have to inject jquery in angular.module(), the only possible reason i see is the angularfilesort().

Comment: Mohit shah's answer below seems to be contextually correct and worth trying part is injecting jquery above app.min.js manually.. If that doesnt solve then just comment here.. I ll implement it to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/besr6sju/

```
<div class="row" id="top-banner">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-11">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" >Movie Flix</a>
                <input type="search" class="search-box" placeholder="Search" >
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Type <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Movies</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Series</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Genre <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Adventure</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Sci-Fi</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Thriller</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Crime</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Talkshow</a></li>


                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                        <li><a href="#">Drama</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Fantasy</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Comedy</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Biography</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Documentary</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">War</a></li>


                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                        <li><a href="#">Mystery</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Romance</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Western</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Animation</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Horror</a></li>

                                        <li><a href="#">Family</a></li>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                    </li>


                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.navbar-collapse-->
        </nav>
    </div>


</div>
```

Your dropdown is working fine. Can you please specify the exact issue?

Comment: Hi Mohit, Thanks for your response. When I run this separately its working fine. When I use gulp to inject dependencies and run the drop down is not working.

Comment: There can be either two problems. Either it can be the order of the links in the index ie jquery first then bootstrap.js or if you are including main app.js (file created after gulp) then include jquery first and then include bootstrap.js in it.  @dharan

Comment: I am not manually inserting dependencies. I am using Gulp for it.

Comment: Angularfilesort might inject bootstrap.js first and then jquery... @dharan

Comment: I think jquery is getting injected first.I can see that in index.html after.

Comment: Index.html would have only app.min.js and app.min.css@dharan

Comment: Try manually injecting jquery above app.min.js in Index.html and I believe it will work like a charm

Comment: Then try removing angularfilesort @dharan

Comment: Then rename jquery so it comes first while sorting.. As in 1-jquery.js.. Or may be you can simply keep jquery injected separately.. @dharan

Comment: Moreover inserting manually is a safe approach according to me because that's to be done only once.. And you look have all the control of the injected scripts and their order

Comment: May be ill insert only jquery manually.  Rest of the stuff is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Include the jquery.js script before the bootstrap.js in footer.

Comment: I am using Gulp to inject dependencies.